# Solving two equations with 2 variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am wondering if this equations can be solved by "a" and "b":

> b = 1 + 0.31*a
>
> a = c1 - c2/b

c1 and c2 are constants, but change depending on some initial assumptions.
One example of their values is:
c1 = 0.25
c2 = 0.4
So the initial equations could like this:

> b = 1+0.31*a
>
> a = 0.25 - 0.4/b

Can they be solved for "a" and "b"?

Thank you.

Comment: replace $a$ in the first equation by $c1-c2/b$ and then multiply the equation by $b$. You will end up with a quadratic equation in $b$ which can be solved using standard techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$b = 1+0.31*a\\
a = 0.25 - 0.4/b\\
\\\implies ab=0.25b-0.4\\
\implies a(1+0.31a)=0.25(1+0.31a)-0.4\\
\implies a+0.31a^2=0.25+0.0775a-0.4\\
\implies 0.9225a+0.31a^2+0.15=0$

Yikes! A painful quadratic equation to solve, but will give you a and then b.

Comment: Thank you MonK. How can I solve this quadratic equation?
Can I solve like this:
"a1,2 = ( -0.9225±sqrt((-0.9225)^2 - 4*0.31*0.15) )  /  (2 * 0.31)"
  ?  I am getting  a1 = -0.17   and   a2 = -2.8. But I am not suppose to get negative values for "a" variable, so I have to be doing something wrong.

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong, I got the same answers. Your $a$ value can be negative.

Comment: Thank you L.A.F.2. Something is wrong with my initial equations then.
"b" is suppose to always be larger or equal to 1. With "a" being negative, I am always getting "b" to be less than 1.